# Natural decay resistant wood

Tags: framing

Which wood does the icc not recognize as decay resistant? It is either western red cedar or redwood, cannot find in code book.

Answer (score 4):

You didn’t indicate where you’re from, but The ICC Code identifies “Decay Probability Map” in Figure R301.2(7) which includes a strip along the entire west coast and a wide strip from Iowa south to the tip of Texas and from Iowa east to Massachusetts and extending south through Florida.

Likewise, Section R319.1 requires pressure treated lumber “or decay resistant heartwood of redwood, black locust, or cedars.”

Also, decay resistant lumber is required for “buildings and structures constructed in flood hazard areas.”

Comment: Informative... didn't know about the Decay probability Map.+1

Comment: Isn't teak usually included in lists of naturally decay resistant woods, or is it just _very_ hard? I know velodromes are usually decked in teak, and many are outdoors.

Comment: @FreeMan Hmmm...Teak isn’t mentioned but is often used on boats, I think.